# What does $q.defer() in following code in angularjs context

Tags: angularjs

What is the use of $q.defer() in following code. I am bit confused or not able to understand the use of $q or defer?

```
  service.serviceCall = function (methodName, params) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({ method: "POST", url: url + methodName, data: params, headers: headers }).success(function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    }).error(function (result) {
        deferred.reject(result);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: here headers is : var headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "dataType": "json" };

Comment: Read about promises: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Then go through the $q module docs in angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0):

```
service.serviceCal("POST", {"param1":"value1"}).then(function(data){
  //here data will be object which is resolved in success call
}).fail(function(){
 //here data will be object which is rejected in failure call
})
```

This are promises, we user $q.defer() to return a promise using defer.promise(). It is contract between the calling object and promise that in future the calling object (here then and fail) will ultimately get a value either in then or fail depends whether it is resolved or rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Read about promises here: [Promises](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html)

Go through docs of $q module: [$q Module Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

> A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their
>   return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.

So promises are used in async programming. $q is Angular's implementation of promises.

Usage of the above function:

```
service.serviceCal(methodName, params)
.then(function(resolve){

    // on successful resolving
    // called when defer.resolve is called
    // resolved object: resolve

}, function(reject){

    // on reject
    // called when defer.reject is called
    // rejected object: reject

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is using deprecated methods on the result of calling `$http`. Although `$http` returns a promise it has some additional methods `.success` and `.error` that don't quite work within the usual promise structure.

`$q.defer()` creates a promise which is returned from the function and this code uses `success` and `error` to resolve the promise. A simpler way to write this code would be to just use the promises returned by `$http` and its `.then` method.

```
  service.serviceCall = function (methodName, params) {
    return $http({ method: "POST", url: url + methodName, data: params, headers: headers })
    .then(function successFn (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

This has the same effect as the original code: it returns a promise which either resolves to the data from the response, or if an error occurs the promise is rejected.