# promise is used with both $http and $q async call. when is preferable to use promise either with $http or $q

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to understand the scenario either  to use $q or $http for a asynchronous  call and handling result set using promise ?

when can we use deferred API?

Comment: refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508088/what-does-q-defer-in-following-code-in-angularjs-context/40508348#40508348

Comment: Understand the concept of promises: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: One design pattern is where you wrap your $http calls within $q.defer() segments. You should place your $http calls in services, enclose them within $q.defer() blocks and call the wrapper function in your controllers

Comment: @aliasav no, that's horrible. This is the worst thing that could happen to an $http service...